# Make calculation include decimals

Tags: javascript, html-table, decimal

I am new to Javascript and I got most of this code from another Q&A on this site worked great! Only problem is that the code doesn't count the decimals! How do I get this code to count the decimals?

```
<table> <tr class=r1> 
<th class=d1>1-24</th> 
<th class=d2>25-49</th> 
<th class=d2>50-99</th> 
<th class=d2>100-499</th> 
<th class=d2>500 = Offert</th> 
        <tr class=r1> 
        <td class=d1 id=A>99,00:-</td> 
        <td class=d2 id=B></td> 
        <td class=d2 id=C></td> 
        <td class=d2 id=D></td> 
        <td class=d2> </td> </tr>
</table>
```

That's the table I have to make a bracket price.

This is the Javascript:

```
(function(){
// put all your JavaScript in a closure so you don't pollute the global namespace
  function extract_float_from_price ( price ) {
    return parseFloat( price.replace(/\:*-/,'') );
  }

  function evaluate_savings ( ) {
    var A = extract_float_from_price( $('#A').text() );

    $('#B').text( parseInt(A * 0.96 ) + ':-' );
        $('#C').text( parseInt(A * 0.92 ) + ':-' );
        $('#D').text( parseInt(A * 0.88 ) + ':-' );
  }

  $( evaluate_savings ); // binds to Dom Ready
})()
```

Please help me get the code to show decimals for a more exact price.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`parseFloat`](http://docs.jquery.com/Types#Parsing_Numbers) rather than parseInt in the following statements

```
    $('#B').text( parseFloat(A * 0.96 ) + ':-' );
    $('#C').text( parseFloat(A * 0.92 ) + ':-' );
    $('#D').text( parseFloat(A * 0.88 ) + ':-' );
```

BTW, it is great that some answer helped you do something, but you should also try to understand what the code does and how it does when you use it.

And, [Java != Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)

**Update**:

To round a number use [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed). 
You might want to do:

```
$('#B').text( parseFloat(A * 0.96 ).toFixed(2) + ':-' );
```

and so on

Comment: Yeah I know, Im working on a project and didn't know I was gonna have to use javascript, I really want to learn it for real but for now, I have to "cheat" and I am really greatful for your help.

Comment: Only thing now that's missing is how I get the prize to show with only 2 decimals?

Answer (score 0):

Something to learn immediately, so you get better responses in future, this is JavaScript *not* Java.  They look similar, but are by no means the same.  There are plenty of discussions on the Internet describing the differences.

In answer to your question, try the JavaScript function `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`.

Comment: thanks for the help it worked great, I am new to this so I didn't know there was a difference sry

Comment: One problem with this, I only want two decimals, how can I keep the generated answer to only two decimals

Comment: parseFloat( value ).toFixed( 2 )

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two things

- use `parseFloat`
- replace `,` with `.` as . is the comma separator in javascript.

So,

```
// get the part of the text that should be parsed
var A = /[\d,.]+/.exec($('#A').text())[0];

// replace any , with .
A = A.replace(",",".")

// parse the string into a Number
A = A.parseFloat(A, 10);

// output the result
$('#B').text( (A * 0.96)  + ':-' );
```

should work for you